# Returning a Uri from onActivityResult() to the main intent

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I am developing an app in which one of the components is to open a file. Right now I have written a 'performFileSearch' method to open a file search as below :

```
public void performFileSearch() {
            // ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is the intent to choose a file via the system's file
            // browser.

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

            // Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as a
            // file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones)
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

            // Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
            // If one wanted to search for ogg vorbis files, the type would be "audio/ogg".
            // To search for all documents available via installed storage providers,
            // it would be "*/*".

            //Mime Types : https://developers.google.com/drive/web/mime-types
            intent.setType("*/*");
           // Intent resultData = intent;
           // READ_REQUEST_CODE = 1, defined as a global variable
            startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
```

After this method executes, 'onActivityResult' method is called :

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent resultData) {

        // super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

        if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE
                && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri uri = null;
            if (resultData != null) {
                test = false;
                uri = resultData.getData();
                ur1 = uri;
                try {
                    // You can ignore the try part, I'm interested in just the
                    // URL
                    String msg = readTextFromUri(uri);
                    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                    textView.setText(msg);
                    setContentView(textView);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());

            }

        }
    }
```

I have declared ur1 as a global variable to store the uri value retrieved from the onActivityResult method but the ur1 value is always null.

I call the 'performFileSearch()' from the onCreate method of my class but during debugging, I not that even after the 'performFileSearch()' method returns, the ur1 value is still null.

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.roster_recycle);
            rObject = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            rObject.setLayoutManager(llm);

            MyCards c1 = new MyCards("Abhinav", 123, true);
            MyCards c2 = new MyCards("Abhishek", 13, false);
            performFileSearch();
            onResume();
            c1.setName("Abhinav");
            c2.setName("Baba");
            List<MyCards> cardList = new ArrayList<MyCards>();
            cardList.add(c1);
            cardList.add(c2);
            adapter = new MyAdapter(Roster.this,cardList);
            rObject.setAdapter(adapter);
          //  Log.e(Tag, ur1.toString());
        }
```

However, I wrote an onResume() method and realised that after the control goes into the onResume method, I get ur1 value. The code first goes through all the steps in onCreate() method and only after that, onResume() is called.

My question is : Is there a way to retrieve the URL within the onCreate method itself?

Comment: Don't call onResume() yourself as it is for the OS to invoke it. If you did check ur1 in onResume then you were to early. It makes no sense to use ur1 in on Create as onCreate is already long time finished before even the user can pick a file.

Comment: So how can I wait until the user has picked the file?

Comment: You do nothing. And onActivityResult is called when the user picked a file. So there you should do what you want with the file.

Comment: Yeah, I am doing exactly the the same. I am parsing the file by calling a method from inside onActivityResult but I also want to store the URI of the file in a variable. One solution is to call all the methods from onResume() because first the whole of onCreate method executes and then only the URI gets a non-null value when onResume() gets called.

Comment: All makes no sense to me. First you want to wait until the user picked a file. So you wait until onActivity result gets called and you handle the file. You also want go store its uri. Ok. But for what? Please tell first. All you tell about onResume and on its methods -methods of onResume???- makes no sense to me.